# How to fix hal.dll is missing error in a dual boot system?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, multi-boot, mbr

I have both windows 7 and xp installed. If there was only xp, I would go ahead and boot up the  xp installation disc and re install the hal.dll file from the recovery console. 
Problem is I have also windows 7 installed, and I'm thinking that I will also be unable to boot windows 7 once xp is fixed. Please help.

Comment: Why? if you copy hal to the proper partition.

Comment: I already did that. But still xp cannot boot

Comment: Have you added or removed disks lately? Have you deleted or added partions?

Comment: Run a chkdsk on the XP partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different versions of the hal.dll, XP installation chooses the correct version based on your hardware configuration in the bios. So yould need to know which hal.dll to copy into XP, Most PC's use one of the Hal's marked with a bullet below.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309283

> "Standard PC," Non-ACPI PIC HAL (Hal.dll)
>   Standard PC
>
> "MPS Uniprocessor PC," Non-ACPI APIC UP HAL (Halapic.dll)
>   Standard PC
>   MPS Uniprocessor
>   MPS Multiprocessor
>
> "MPS Multiprocessor PC," Non-ACPI APIC MP HAL (Halmps.dll)
>   Standard PC
>   MPS Multiprocessor
>
> - "Advanced Configuration and Power Interface (ACPI) PC," ACPI PIC HAL (Halacpi.dll)
>     Standard PC
>     Advanced Configuration and Power Interface (ACPI) PC
> - "ACPI Uniprocessor PC," ACPI APIC UP HAL (Halaacpi.dll)
>     Standard PC
>     Advanced Configuration and Power Interface (ACPI) PC
>     ACPI Uniprocessor
>     ACPI Multiprocessor
>
> "ACPI Multiprocessor PC," ACPI APIC MP HAL (Halmacpi.dll)
>   Standard PC
>   Advanced Configuration and Power Interface (ACPI) PC
>   ACPI Multiprocessor
>   MPS Multiprocessor

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts are that your boot.ini for XP is not pointing to the right partition, not necessarily that the hal.dll is wrong. You will get that error in that case.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/330184

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jvMkt9fkHCI

Comment: Supplemental: Go into your Windows 7 side, and go into the disk manager. Figure out what number disk the XP install is on (it tells you very clearly the disk number), and which partition it is on on that disk. Post back that info, and a the contents of your XP boot.ini file, and I will look at it.

Comment: You should edit that into your answer.

Comment: I will edit the answer after I get the information and can add something specific to the answer.

Comment: windows 7 and xp are both installed on the same disk. which is disk 0. windows 7 is in partition 0, and xp is in partition 3. I used diskpart to get this information. I tried to search for the boot.ini file using everything(void tools): 
;Warning: Boot.ini is used on Windows XP and earlier operating systems.
;Warning: Use BCDEDIT.exe to modify Windows Vista boot options.
;
[boot loader]
timeout=1
default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(2)\WINDOWS
[operating systems]
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(2)\WINDOWS="Microsoft Windows XP Professional" /NOEXECUTE=OPTIN /FASTDETECT

Comment: the boot.ini file is not in the partition where xp is installed. It's in a primary partition which I use for saving my files.